# PHP Mysql explode String and check

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field called brands. In brands i am imploding the arrays and saving it. 
Like 51,60.

for search i am using the following query.

```
SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE brands LIKE '%51%'
```

this is working but its also return the values with 151,510.

how to find the value for 50 only?

Thanks to all

Comment: if value 51,60 LIKE '51%'

Comment: By looking on your query line - it should work fine. what error does it shows

Comment: sorry, i updated the question please check now.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE brands LIKE '%51%' this query returns the records which is having the values like 151,510

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE FIND_IN_SET("51",brands)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is correct. if you want for 50 just put or condition with the existing on like

```
SELECT * FROM `user_profile` WHERE brands like '%51%' or  course_code like '50'
```

Comment: What is the difference between proposed and existing query ?

Comment: So, Your suggestions should be only as a comment and not as an `answer`

Comment: SELECT * FROM `user_profiles` WHERE brands LIKE '%51%' this query returns the records which is having the values like 151,510